# A text is displayed in debug mode but not displayed in release mode

Tags: react-native

[image: This is when in debug mode is off[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Latq.jpg)
[[image: This is when in debug mode]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrIt0.jpg)
I have a react native app and I want to display text string getting from the api but I am able to see the string when I am in debug mode but when I turn off the debug mode I am not able to see the string.

```
    <Text style={{ ...styles.oswaldBold12Black }}>
      {props[mode] &&
       props[mode][monthIndex] &&
       props[mode][monthIndex]["week"] &&
       props[mode][monthIndex]["week"][selectedWeek - 1] &&
       props[mode][monthIndex]["week"][selectedWeek - 1]
       .dayObj &&
        props[mode][monthIndex]["week"][selectedWeek - 1]
        .dayObj[value] &&
        props[mode][monthIndex]["week"][selectedWeek - 1]
        .dayObj[value]["weekDay"] &&
        props[mode][monthIndex]["week"][selectedWeek - 1]
        .dayObj[value]["weekDay"].substring(0,3)}
        </Text>
```

Comment: first, not being in debug mode doesn't mean release mode. second, in debug mode your code runs on the debugger's js engine and when debugging is disabled your code runs on your phone (or emulator) which makes different behavior in some packages. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50861731/react-native-different-behaviour-between-debug-mode-and-normal-mode

Comment: thanks I have found another way to handle this issue

Comment: @Prajwal how you handle this issue?